# comparing date objects in as2

Tags: flash, actionscript, date, comparison, actionscript-2

I must be missing something.

```
date1 = new Date(2010, 01, 10, 12, 10, 30, 000);
date2 = new Date(2010, 01, 10, 12, 10, 30, 000);

trace(date1 == date2); // returns false
```

However,

```
date1 = new Date(2010, 01, 10, 12, 10, 30, 000);
date2 = new Date(2010, 01, 10, 12, 10, 30, 000);

trace(date1.toString() == date2.toString()); // returns true
```

So... what's going on? Obviously the two date objects are somehow subtly different, and that difference somehow gets overlooked when they're parsed out as strings, but *how* are they different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare two objects like this, what you are really comparing is their object identity, on a lower level, their positions in RAM. When you do `new Date()`, that creates a new object, so the two objects will not match, even though the values stored therein do.

Comparing strings however is a special case where the strings are compared character-by-character rather than comparing their positions in memory.

A common way to compare dates is using their `time` property, which is a Number representing the Date object as UNIX time, i.e. seconds since the start of the UNIX epoch at 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

```
trace(date1.time == date2.time); // traces "true"
```

Cheers

Comment: crazy - I guess I thought that kind of comparison only took place if you use the '===' operator - that '==' compares values, '===' compares the actual unique variables themselves. But not so much, huh? Good to know, thanks!

Comment: The `==` and `===` operators are identical (apart from strings, I think, and even then they can be interned). The flash runtime has no support for overriding equality so `==` is always a reference comparision.